# Using the adjectives 'very' and 'own' for our (own!) body organs

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

The adjectives 'very' and 'own' mean *precisely as stated* or *being exactly the same and not any other.* I understand a subtle difference between *my bike* and *my own bike* in below mentioned instance -

> **Case #1**: I parked a bike. A policeman asked me the papers of the vehicle. The papers belonged to the owner (my cousin) whose bike I had borrowed for that day. But then for the policeman, it is **my** bike. Even I would say *"Yes, I'm sorry that I parked **my** bike here in a No Parking zone."*
>   
>  
>   **Case #2**: I had to reach there as early as possible. Had it been **my own bike**, I would have gone at the speed of 100 kmph but I am very responsible and cautious while riding my cousin's bike. You know, it's very costly.

Now the question:

In above mentioned case, it's vehicle and hence the use of *my* and *my own* seems quite acceptable. **But then when we use the same for our organs, why use *own* at all? We own them since our birth!**

> *Yeah! Trust me. I saw her with him with **my very eyes**!*
>   
>   *Don't you believe me? I did it with **my own hands.***

Comment: Maulik, I'd just like to say that you've been posting some very interesting questions (especially this one!) and I appreciate your contribution to ELL :)  Keep it up! I wish I were able to answer this question for you; the answer is floating around somewhere in my head, but not in any way I know how to explain.

Comment: @WendiKidd Thank you, sir. Being a non-native speaker (it's so sad!), I'm very enthusiastic learning the language. I find here the bunch of gurus, the real gurus like you and thus feel heavenly. :)

Comment: @MaulikV For future reference, most people named Wendi are not sirs :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree with the premise of the question. Case #2 could be written "Had it been my bike, I ...". Similarly your other sentence could be "I saw her with my very own eyes". "(I did it) by my own hands" on the other hand (no pun intended) is a fixed idiom, meaning "(I did it) myself"

Comment: @Matt. No. *Had it been my bike...* wouldn't have worked there. Because I want to convey that had it been *my own thing* I wouldn't have care speeding it on a rough road as my *own* bike is old. My cousin's bike is costly and I should take utter care that nothing happens to it. In other words, I won't use others' things roughly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had taken up woodwork as a hobby and made your first object, lets say a wooden jewellery box, and someone asked you:

> That looks beautiful. Did you make it?

You would proudly assert:

> Yes, I did actually. I made that box with **my** (very) **own** hands.

Note, you could (idiomatically) insert *very* in the phrase without changing the meaning. 
The fact you place the adjective, *own* between the possessive adjective, *my*, and the noun, *hands*, means you are emphasizing the **ownership** of the hands that crafted the object. If you had replied:

> I made that box with **my hands**.

Your listener would understand that you were the carpenter or maker of this object but it would sound odd, because you can't make an object with someone else's hands. You would never say: "Yes, I made it with *his* hands". It sounds not only gruesome (!) but obviously illogical. More typical expressions would be:

- Yes, it's **handmade**
- Yes, I **made** it **by hand**

The above expressions tell your listener that the object is crafted by hand, that very little machinery was involved in the process or if that were not the case, that you handled the machinery or mechanical tools yourself.

A more unusual way to express the same idea would be to say:

- I made it with these ***very*** hands

I would place the stress on "very" and probably hold my hands, palm upwards, to show the various cuts, nicks, scars and calluses that might be present as evidence that I am an experienced carpenter.

The [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+hand%2Cown+hands%2Chandmade%2Cmade+by+hand%2C+very+hands&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cown%20hands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chandmade%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20by%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20hands%3B%2Cc0) seems to be heavily in favour of "by hand" but please do look at the different links below the chart to see how each expression can be used.

---

EDIT: *Very* when it is used as an adjective

There is a very famous and beautiful song sung by Nat King Cole entitled

[The Very Thought Of You](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaYLWSo4fYM)

The first two lines are

> The very thought of you and I forget to do
>   The little ordinary things that everyone ought to do

In these lines, "very" means *mere*, *simple*, and *plain*. Just the simple thought of his loved one is enough to make him forget about the dull and insignificant moments of his daily routine. The meaning is slightly different from that quoted by the OP, *"precisely as stated or being exactly the same and not any other"*

However, returning to the OP's sentence,

> Yeah! Trust me. I saw her with him with my very eyes

in this example *very* carries another different meaning. The Chambers Dictionary gives the definition for "very" used this way

> adj. used for emphasis, [...] precise,
>   actual (*this very minute, her very words*)

Thus the speaker is emphasizing that he *saw* the woman with a man, presumably not her real partner, with his actual eyes (in other words he didn't hear the news from anyone else) and therefore, to take his word for it.

Comment: This clarifies a bit, especially the *proud* part. Yes, we do use *very own* or *my own* at least as a lofty response if not in utter proud.

Comment: Nice post. This is the first time I notice that "very" has negative connotation. It is quite easy to imagine a suspect finally cracks after hours of intense interrogation. *"Tell us! How did you kill her?"* Then he cried out, *"I killed her with these very hands."*

Comment: That's a very good example! @DamkerngT.

Comment: @DamkerngT I don't think *very* has a negative connotation.

Comment: DamkerngT. I'm with @snailboat; I don't think there's any negative connotation associated with *very*. The *context* is negative, but that could be true in any case. Mari-Lou, this is an excellent answer! (So many of those from you lately :)). +1! My only quibble is with your *handmade* examples. The first and second don't sound idiomatic to me (though the third does). "Handmade by me" sounds odd. "Yes, it is handmade" would be used (without the *by me*) when you're pointing out that an object was made by hand, but *not* by you; ex. "Oh, I love these vases! The imperfections make them really

Comment: unique. Did you get them at the bazaar last week?" "Yep! They're handmade, too." There is a level of depersonalization here; you almost never say something is *handmade* when *you* made it. Similarly, we don't say "I handmade it myself". (In fact we never use *handmade* as a verb; it's always an adjective.) If I wanted to express this sentiment, I would use your third example, which is indeed idiomatic; "Yes, I made it by hand." @MaulikV

Comment: @snailboat and WendiKidd: Thank you for the concerns. I probably should added '..."very" has negative connotation *in this kind of context*', for the sake of other learners. But then again, I wouldn't believe that any beginners will think "very" has negative meaning in sentences like *Thank you very much,* or intermediate learners will mistaken "very" as a bad quality in *Two thousand years ago, they built the city on this very ground* (where the speaking is standing upon). I don't know if my idea on negative connotation is linguistically correct. But I can recall someone got blamed,

Comment: (continued) *Isn't it you who messed this up?* That "you" was stressed, and it had very very strong negative connotation. The thing is, after reading this answer, I tried to come up with examples for the constructs: *my sth.*, *my own sth.*, *my very (own) sth.*, and I couldn't come up with even one instance of *my very sth.* that wasn't used in negative context or with negative expectation, which surprised me *very* much.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh, I don't think the negative connotation comes from *very* in these contexts.  I can come up with positive examples for *my*, *my very*, *my own*, and *my very own*: "**My** beloved daughter, home at last!" "And before **my very** eyes, the firefighter appeared from the flames carrying my baby, safe and sound! It was a miracle!" "Oh, try some of this stuffing.  It's **my own** recipe!" "I made it with **my very own** hands and filled it with love!"  (I made up the first three examples and found the fourth on the web.)

Comment: @snailboat: If you read my last comment once again, you will see that I have no problem with other constructs but *my very sth.*. What I meant was that given the choices between *my very* and *my own*, it appeared (at least to me at that time) that I was unable to think of the use of *my very* in a good way. (I also tried *my very eyes*, but then I came up in the context that one girl trying to tell her friend that her friend's boyfriend is cheating on her.) Now your firefighter example is interesting since it counters my earlier intuition quite well. Thank you.