# Is "the very end" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, usage

I've come across this news about ['music and love are the only truly international languages'](http://www.someecards.com/entertainment/music/korean-bass-player-italian-street-musicians-autumn-leaves/), and found this:

> "Towards **the very end**, the video gets a little shaky as even the person filming starts tapping their foot."

Why use **the very end**?  The **end** of something means there is no more.
Is there a difference in meaning between **the end** and **then very end**?

Comment: Sure. Why not..?

Comment: @user3169 It is used to emphasize?

Comment: Yes it is correct, it means just very close to the ending, more so than just "the end".

Comment: Useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/using-the-adjectives-very-and-own-for-our-own-body-organs

Comment: Also useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84155 There are better questions out there about the strange ways very is used in English. I don't think this question should be re-opened even with Peter's edits.

Comment: I agree with ColleenV, especially because its definition can be found in the first dictionary I tried: **[very](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/very)**: used for emphasizing an extreme place or time, for example at the top or end of something; *Can you see that little bird right up at the very top of the tree? Nick was sitting in the very back of the bus. We worked till the very end of the day. She smoked her cigarette down to the very end, then stubbed it out.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **the very end**

is grammatically correct

> We watched the movie until **the very end**

that is until there was no more movie left.

**Very** is used to emphasize the closeness to the end-of-the-end, as opposed to the-beginning-of-the-end.

For example, a rope has an exact end, however it can be referred to as

> **the end** of the rope
>   **the very end** of the rope
>   **the bitter end** of the rope

Comment: Erm... *the **bitter** end of the **rope*** is not idiomatic. Only ***time-based*** referents can have a "bitter end".

Comment: @fumbleFingers: The bitter end, when used about rope,  is actually a naval term used to refer to the last six fathoms of an anchor rope. This was often painted bright colours to make sure that sailors didn't carry on letting out anchor rope and let go of the end, losing anchor and rope.

Comment: [Bitter End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot#Bitter_end).  There is also a nightclub on Bleecker St in NYC called "The Bitter End".

Comment: @JavaLatte: Oh wow! I didn't know that's apparently where the cliche *came* from in the first place: [*A **bitt** on a ship is something that you can wind a rope round; the loops of the rope are **bitters**, and the **bitter end** is the end of this rope.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m3MEbgED8eQC&pg=PT32&dq=%22bitter+end%22+%22rope%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22bitter%20end%22%20%22rope%22&f=false) I'll leave my first comment as enduring testament to my [previous] ignorance.

Comment: You can say "they watched the film to the bitter end" even if the film had a happy ending: when I was young, I was very confused by this.

Comment: Amazing @FumbleFingers I could never think of that without the explanation!

Comment: Yes, like between the devil and the deep blue sea. Well done,Peter.